# How to SELECT the total row number as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

My first query

```
SELECT
    id,
    year_,
    month_
FROM
    (SELECT
         tp.id,
         YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as year_, 
         MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as month_,
         @rn := IF(@prev = CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date))), @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
         @prev := CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)))
     FROM 
         tr_place tp
     JOIN 
         (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
     ORDER BY 
         YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC, 
         MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC) AS T1
WHERE 
    rn < 3;
```

Will returns the data set [This is the result which I got from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXbfz.png)

The subquery in it

```
SELECT
    tp.id,
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as year_, 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as month_,
    @rn := IF(@prev = CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date))), @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
    @prev := CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)),MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)))
 FROM 
     tr_place tp
 JOIN 
     (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
 ORDER BY 
     YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC,
     MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC;
```

Returns data [The sub query will returns this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nqb6.png)

I need the subquery's greatest `rn` as a column in the first query.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a problem with variable assignment.  You should not be referencing variables in multiple expressions in the `select`.  So, the correct way to write the first query is:

```
SELECT id, year_, month_
FROM (SELECT tp.id,
             YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as year_, 
             MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) as month_,
             (@rn := IF (@prev = CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date))), @rn,
                         if(@prev := CONCAT(YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date))), 1, 1
                        )
             ) as rn
      FROM tr_place tp JOIN
           (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
      ORDER BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC, 
               MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tp.visited_date)) DESC
     ) t1
WHERE rn < 3;
```

Note the variable assignments are all in a single expression.

This may fix your issue.

Comment: @Travalourdeveloper . . . That doesn't help much.  You should say what the error is (probably a misbalanced parentheses).

Comment: It's a misplaced comma. Well, the moment's proabably passed.